# How to fix "No interaction found for POST /" (and GET /)?

Tags: c#, pact

```
"message": "No interaction found for POST /",
"interaction_diffs": []

"message":"No interaction found for GET /",
"interaction_diffs":[]
```

I could see couple of times the GET call worked, no change of code, also pact file got generated. but not happening consistently.

Pact config looks like this

```
 var pactConfig = new PactConfig
   {
            SpecificationVersion = "2.4.6",

            PactDir = @"..\..\..\..\..\pacts",
            LogDir = @".\pact_logs"
   };

   PactBuilder = new PactBuilder(pactConfig);

   PactBuilder.ServiceConsumer("Consumer")
                   .HasPactWith("Provider");
```

Also to note, im yet to write Provider because I thought of verifying the mockup part and then go for verification on Provider side.

Answer (score 3):

Get or Post calls were not working as there was mismatch between requested uri and mocked uri. Found out through provider_mock_service log.

Answer (score 0):

If google brought you here, in my case it was a lack of leading slash in `.with_request()`